# Do the same conditions apply for the same trading pair on the same exchange in different jurisdictions?

Tags: exchanges

If an American resident in the US and a Canadian resident in Canada had 1btc each and they each converted it on Binance to USDT, would they get the same result?

Comment: Yes as long as the exchanges give the same rate of bitcoin because USDT means United States Dollar tether. So it will equal one US dollar not Canadian dollar. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: No because they are in different jurisdictions. This question is off topic at this subsite and applies elsewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by *"get the same result"*?

Comment: @chytrik I mean would the converted USDT amount be the same in both cases?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question boils down to:

- Can businesses charge different prices for their services in different markets? Yes they can and sometimes do. For example, in the case of a currency exchange this might be represented as a different spread between buying and selling prices or in a transaction charge. Arbitrage limits this, especially for online services.
- Can different countries impose different regulations that have some effect on retail prices? Yes, different governments might have differing rules about   either taxation or some other regulatory burden that businesses try to recover the cost of from their source of income
- Does Changpeng Zhao love his compatriots more than he loves south north Americans? Probably not.
- In this regard is any Bitcoin related business significantly different from any other type of financial business? Is it different from general business? Probably not as much as many folk seem to think.